# CiviVolunteer New Project issues

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer, settings

I have CiviCRM 5.34 CiviVolunteer 2.4.1 and Angular Profiles 4.7.31-1.1.1 on Wordpress 5.6.1  I am logged in as the Admin.

I have freshly installed and set up.  I try to create a new project and the screen loads but I can't save the project.  When I go to manage a project I get Error relationship_type_id is not a valid integer  I looked and it is there in the option groups.  There are no options in there.

I have no project relationships set up

When I try to load the volunteer interest form I get DB Error: no such field

I can load the search screen with no problem

How can I get the volunteer extension up and running?